# Creating custom core data Class to subclass MKAnnotation?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to save MKAnnotations into core data for a project in a course I'm taking.

I've looked at the code from other students on github and they've all taken the same approach of creating a custom NSManagedObject class that subclasses MKAnnotation.

```
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    set {
       ...
    }
    get {
       ...
    }
}

override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
}

init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

    super.init(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
   self.lat = ....
}
```

I don't understand the super.inits.

MKAnnotation requires a coordinate variable which explains the first set of code, so that makes sense.

In the 2nd and 3rd snippets of code, what is the purpose of overriding the init an calling the super.init? Every example on github has very similar code to this so is this the ONLY way to approach this? Why is it necessary to do it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `MKAnnotation` is a protocol, not a class. You can't subclass two different classes, but you can have a subclass that adopts as many protocols as you like. But that's not directly related to your class.

The reason for the `super.init` calls is nothing directly to do with Core Data. It's more about Swift initialization. Every class has at least one "designated" initializer. Swift requires that these classes call their superclass's designated initializer. `NSManagedObject`'s designated initializer is `init(entity:, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)`, so any subclass **must** call that to complete initialization.

There's more to Swift's initialization rules when it comes to class inheritance. You might want to review [Apple's documentation on the subject](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) if it hasn't been covered in your course.